# Replace some specific items of an array with the elements of another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before, but here is the deal -

Suppose, there are two `arrays`

```
var arrOne = ['Q', '_', 'E', 'R', '_', 'Y'];
var arrTwo = ['W', 'Y'];
```

How can I replace those the blanks *`_`* of `arrOne` with the elements of `arrTwo`?

The output should be an array -

```
['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'Y', 'Y']
```

Comment: what is the desired result. have you tried something?

Comment: please share code what you tried so far

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `index` and get a new array using `map` like this:

```js
var arrOne = ['Q', '_', 'E', 'R', '_', 'Y'];
var arrTwo = ['W', 'Y'];

let index = 0;
const newArray = arrOne.map(a => a === "_" ? arrTwo[index++] : a)

console.log(newArray)
```

If you're fine with `arrTwo` being removed of its values every time it replaces, then you can use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```js
var arrOne = ['Q', '_', 'E', 'R', '_', 'Y'];
var arrTwo = ['W', 'Y'];

const newArray = arrOne.map(a => a === "_" ? arrTwo.shift() : a)

console.log(newArray)
```

If you want to update the values in the original array itself (mutation):

```js
var arrOne = ['Q', '_', 'E', 'R', '_', 'Y'];
var arrTwo = ['W', 'Y'];

arrOne.forEach((a,i) => arrOne[i] = a === "_" ? arrTwo.shift() : a)
console.log(arrOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` loop for this

```js
var arrOne = ['Q', '_', 'E', 'R', '_', 'Y'];
var arrTwo = ['W', 'Y'];

arrOne.forEach((e) => {
  if (e == '_') {
    arrOne[arrOne.indexOf(e)] = arrTwo[0];
    arrTwo.shift();
  }
})
console.log(arrOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to it with a while loop

```
var firstIndex;
var secondIndex = 0;
while ((firstIndex = arrOne.indexOf('_')) >= 0) 
    arrOne[firstIndex] = arrTwo[secondIndex++];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the desired result.

Check this fiddle:

```
var arrOne = ['Q', '_', 'E', 'R', '_', 'Y'];
var arrTwo = ['W', 'Y'];
var pos = 0;

arrOne.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if (e == "_") {
    arrOne[i] = arrTwo[pos];
    pos++;

    if (pos > arrTwo.length) {
        pos = 0;
    }
  }
});

console.log(arrOne);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4cgxho0L/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, some fancy, I am going to just the most imperative way, maybe not the better but you will get the idea and eventually come up with a better solution I am sure of this.

First let's see the code :

```
// we initialise our new array
let new_array = [];

var arrOne = ['Q', '_', 'E', 'R', '_', 'Y'];
var arrTwo = ['W', 'Y'];


// we iterate over each element of the arrOne that we know we want to include in
// our new array
arrOne.forEach(elementOfArrOne => {

// we know also that if we encounter an elementOfArrOne that is equal to '_' we 
// want to add all of the elements of arrTwo
   if (element === '_') {
// that is why when we encounter our '_' we iterate over each item of arrTwo
      arrTwo.forEach(elementOfArrTwo => {
// and we push them into our new_array
          new_array.push(elementOfArrTwo);
      });
   } else {
// if the element that we are iterating on is not '_' then we simply push it to our 
// new_array
     new_array.push(elementOfArrOne);
   }
})
```

EDIT : also, do not be afraid to try things and then come here and expose your attempt. It's so cool to be able to see your code being improved :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over the index and map if necessary the replacement value.

This solution does not mutate any array.

```js
var arrOne = ['Q', '_', 'E', 'R', '_', 'Y'],
    arrTwo = ['W', 'Y'],
    result = arrOne.map((i => v => v === '_' ? arrTwo[i++] : v)(0));

console.log(result);
```